# How to call a PostgreSQL stored function with doctrine

Tags: php, function, postgresql, symfony, doctrine

I try to call some custom function of our PostgreSQL database with doctrine but it doesn't work.

```
$query = $this->_em->getConnection()
           ->prepare('SELECT security.check_login($1, $2, $3, $4, 1, $5, 1, $6, false)');
$query->bindValue(1, 'myname', \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::STRING);
$query->bindValue(2, 'mypass', \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::STRING);
$query->bindValue(3, '35we74', \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::STRING);
$query->bindValue(4, 'a', \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::STRING);
$query->bindValue(5, 'b', \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::STRING);
$query->bindValue(6, '5fuf6d32qbm0hivj739vi8r0t3', \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::STRING);
var_dump($query->execute()); // return false
var_dump($query->fetchColumn()); // return false
```

Does anyone know how to make such query?

Comment: "It doesn't work". What, exactly, does not work? What happens if you do the same thing with `psql`? Since execute returns false, what's the error from the database?

Comment: The same request in pgAdmin return 1, that's mean success.
SELECT security.check_login('myname', 'mypass', '35we74', 'a', 1, 'b', 1, '5fuf6d32qbm0hivj739vi8r0t3', false);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my problem on this thread http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Stored-procedures-PDO-and-PHP-issue-td2211491.html

"You can not use the question mark syntax and the cast.  Instead you have to use the named parameters with the cast."

```
$query = $this->_em->getConnection()->prepare(
        'SELECT security.check_login(:user::VARCHAR, :pass::VARCHAR, :tan::VARCHAR, :tan_h1::VARCHAR, 1, :tan_h2::VARCHAR, 1, :session::VARCHAR, false)');
$query->bindValue(':user', 'myname');
$query->bindValue(':pass', 'mypass');
$query->bindValue(':tan', '35we74');
$query->bindValue(':tan_h1', 'a');
$query->bindValue(':tan_h2', 'b');
$query->bindValue(':session', '5fuf6d32qbm0hivj739vi8r0t3');
```

Comment: Wow, really? And PDO doesn't fail with an error, it just silently butchers the query? Lovely.